# Highly efficient key-value storage in C

Tags: dictionary, hash, key-value-store

What would be the most efficient key-value pair storage algorithm that fulfills the following design goals?

1. Data is stored on disk to avoid data loss if the software / computer does not shut down normally
2. Data is read/written by a single application
3. Runs on desktops so it needs to use the minimal amount of memory, processing and storage so as to minimize the impact to computer performance for the user
4. Must support multiple (2 to 3) inserts/updates per second
5. Expect to have only a few thousand total records but some of these records will be updated frequently (i.e. many times more updates than inserts)
6. Data is only retrieved a few (2 to 3) times a day
7. Data written and retrieved using a single primary numeric key (i.e. short)
8. Will need to frequently update a secondary field (i.e. “key” or “column”) that is used for filtering and sorting the data on retrieval
9. The primary key cannot changed (i.e. does not need to be changed)
10. Records do not need to be removed (i.e. deleting not supported)
11. The application will also store unstructured (i.e. whatever desired by the user) data associated with the keys (primary and secondary)
12. The data associated with the keys can be updated
13. Data is always retrieved as an ordered list, either:
    a.  Starting from the beginning, or
    b.  Filtered by the secondary key

Planning to use this in a C application. The primary criteria for selection is to be as absolutely lightweight and fast as possible.

Answer (score 1):

For C/C++ i'm aware of this variants available

1. https://www.sqlite.org/
2. https://github.com/erthink/libmdbx

Comment: In particular sqilte-lsm-ext.

Comment: Thank you vodolaz and amirouche for the suggestions. sqlite and libmdbx are even heavier than what I want. I was thinking about something I could write in C or a very small library that implements some type of hash algorithm, binary tree or something.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of research, I decided to use LevelDB for this solution. It was easy to build as a static library, and very simple to use within my code. It is super fast and has small file sizes.